Can someone explain how this variable assignment works, in this block of code?
In NestJS's docs, there is a segment on "Code first resolvers", here. The nature of NestJS's function on this is not particularly relevant - I'm more interested in something they did in the code.
In this method
1: async posts(@Parent() author: Author) {
2:     const { id } = author;
3:     return this.postsService.findAll({ authorId: id });
4: }

the Author is an object with many properties, and posts are a collection of Objects that are related to the Author. I understand that in a big picture sense, the method extracts the id of the Author object, and then passes it into the posts query, to find all posts where the authorId === Id supplied.
Where I'm lost is - what happened on line 2? How did that variable assignment happen? I've never seen that type of variable assignment, so I don't even know what to google for, to learn more about it. I've never extracted a property out of an object like that. The variable on the left has no name declaration, it's an implicitly named object with property 'id', and that object does not match the type on the right. I can only assume the id is extracted from the 'id' property in the 'Author' object. But then all of a sudden on line 3, the method somehow knows that 'id' is a variable (and not a property of an unnamed object?) and uses it?
I'm just at a bit of a loss as to what technically happened on line 2. I've never seen that variable assignment before and I would like to learn more about how it works. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

It's called a destructuring assignment. It's the same as const id = author.id
